# Play audio when <span> class higher than amount

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to play audio on a website when value of a certain div/span gets over $100.

The value will be increasing depending on user deposits into a jackpot that runs every 2 minutes.

Current code is

```
<div class="pot-value">
   $
   <span class="current-pot">0</span>
</div>
```

I'd like to play off a "ka-shing" type of sound effect when the value increases over 100.

I want to run additional code as an extension that does this, as I do not own the website.

Is this possible?

Cheers!

Comment: Sure, it's possible. The easiest way would be to check whether it's reached the right amount in the same code that already updates the amount.

Comment: @jpaugh Yeah, well, this isn't my website. I simply want to run some additional code as an extension that does this.

Comment: That's a really important detail to mention in your question. Are you making an extension for a specific browser?

Comment: @jpaugh Yep, my bad on that. Will edit. -- And yeah, probably for Chrome mainly.

Comment: FWIW, there are DOM events to detect when an element has changed, and I'm assuming a browser plugin would have access to that.

Comment: However, this question is (still) pretty broad. I think you'll need to dig in and get some of it done before you'll have enough detail to provide a question which meets [SO]'s standards for "answerable."

Comment: @jpaugh I agree. Thanks for the quick answers, much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the positive attitude! I welcome your future contributions to the site!